# Apache Jackrabbit - Where are my files?

Tags: java, apache, jackrabbit, content-repository, sling

I'm new to Jackrabbit and I'm using Sling to access the repository through its REST interface.  I've figured out how to add and access various files to the repository, but my question is, where is Jackrabbit physically storing these files?

Here is my Jackrabbit repository configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
  or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
  distributed with this work for additional information
  regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
  to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
  "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
  with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
  software distributed under the License is distributed on an
  "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
  KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
  specific language governing permissions and limitations
  under the License.
-->

    <!DOCTYPE Repository
              PUBLIC "-//The Apache Software Foundation//DTD Jackrabbit 2.0//EN"
              "http://jackrabbit.apache.org/dtd/repository-2.0.dtd">

    <Repository>
        <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
             <param name="path" value="/sling-repository/repository"/>
        </FileSystem>

        <DataStore class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.FileDataStore"/>

        <Security appName="Jackrabbit">
            <SecurityManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.DefaultSecurityManager" workspaceName="security">
            </SecurityManager>

            <AccessManager class="org.apache.sling.jcr.jackrabbit.server.impl.security.PluggableDefaultAccessManager">
            </AccessManager>

            <LoginModule class="org.apache.sling.jcr.jackrabbit.server.impl.security.PluggableDefaultLoginModule">
                <param name="anonymousId" value="anonymous"/>
                <param name="adminId" value="admin"/>
            </LoginModule>
        </Security>

        <Workspaces rootPath="/sling-repository/workspaces" defaultWorkspace="default"/>

        <Workspace name="${wsp.name}">
            <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
                <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}"/>
            </FileSystem>
            <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.MySqlPersistenceManager">
              <param name="url" value="jdbc/sling"/>
              <param name="driver" value="javax.naming.InitialContext"/>
              <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="${wsp.name}_"/>
            </PersistenceManager>
            <SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
                <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}/index"/>
                <param name="supportHighlighting" value="true"/>
            </SearchIndex>
        </Workspace>

        <Versioning rootPath="/sling-repository/version">
            <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
                <param name="path" value="/sling-repository/version" />
            </FileSystem>

            <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.MySqlPersistenceManager">
              <param name="url" value="jdbc/sling"/>
              <param name="driver" value="javax.naming.InitialContext"/>
              <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="version_"/>
            </PersistenceManager>
        </Versioning>

        <SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
            <param name="path" value="/sling-repository/repository/index"/>
            <param name="supportHighlighting" value="true"/>
        </SearchIndex>
    </Repository>
```

I'm under the impression that these files should be stored somewhere on the file system since they are larger than 100 bytes (which seems to be the default size limit as described in [Jackrabbit's DataStore documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/DataStore#Configuration)).  So where are they?  I'm not sure where to look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found them!  Since I hadn't overridden the path parameter in the DataStore definition like this:

```
 <DataStore class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.FileDataStore">
        <param name="path" value="/sling-repository/repositorydatastore"/>
 </DataStore>
```

Sling was placing the files into the default `${rep.home}/repository/datastore`  Doh!

[I need to override that value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992830/apache-jackrabbit-override-jackrabbit-configuration-parameters-when-deployed-in).

Answer (score 2):

See also http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/DataStore for the DataStore docs