# Apache Jackrabbit - Override Jackrabbit configuration parameters when deployed in Glassfish v3

Tags: java, apache, jackrabbit, content-repository, sling

I feel like an idiot, but where/how do I override the [Jackrabbit configuration parameters](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jackrabbit-configuration.html#JackrabbitConfiguration-Configurationvariables) when deployed in Glassfish v3?  I've tried setting `rep.home` in the `Glassfish Admin -> Enterprise Server -> System Properties` panel, but it doesn't seem to have any affect.

- Do I have the property name correct?
- Is this not the right place to do
  this?

BTW - I'm using the Jackrabbit release bundled with the Sling API.

Answer (score 0):

The Jackrabbit Configuration Parameters indicated by your link are automatically set by the Jackrabbit Repository implementation when reading the repository.xml configuration file.

What you can do to relocate the Jackrabbit Repository inside Sling is either set the "sling.repository.home" framework property (of the OSGi framework into which Sling is deployed).

Alternatively you can edit the Repository Server configuration in the Web Console *Configuration Manager* page. Select the configuration labeled something like *org.apache.sling.jcr.jackrabbit.server.SlingServerRepository.XXX* where "xxx" looks like UUID string. In that configuration change the Repository Home path. Please note, though, that this will not move your existing repository directory but just tell Sling to use a different location.